# Como criar um botão arredondado no Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Eu estou precisando criar um botão arredondado no Xamarin.Forms parecido com aquele principal do material design, mas sem perder as propriedades de um botão convencional e sem perder a característica de todas as plataformas do xamarin.forms. Gostaria de usar a melhor prática para fazer isso, sem usar gambiarras com imagens etc. Obrigado pessoal!

Edit1: Esqueci de comentar que estou usando o FormsAppCompatActivity para habilitar o material design no Android

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a propriedade `BorderRadius` para criar um botão com os cantos arredondados:

Seguindo a propria [documentação do Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderRadius/):

```
<Button Text="BlueButton"
        BorderColor="Blue"
        BorderRadius = "5"
        BorderWidth = "2"/>
```

Caso esteja tendo problemas para o botão arredondado no Android da pra você fazer 
um render customizado.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace AppCompatRender.Droid
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.CustomButtonBackground);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adicione um novo `Resources/Drawable` que tenha o mesmo nome que você está usando no seu `SetBackgroundResource` por ex. `CustomButtonBackground.axml`, dessa forma difinindo os cantos do retangulo como `10dp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Fiz a tradução [dessa resposta do SOEng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126414/xamarin-border-radius-appcompat)

Comment: Tentei utilizar essa propriedade mas ela não surge efeito algum no meu botão. Tentei diversos valores, tirei outras propriedades para ver se alguma podia influenciar a outra, mas não.

Comment: nao esta funcionando apenas no Android, ou em todos?

Comment: Apenas no Android por conta do FormsAppCompact, eu vi essa resposta também, só que como eu chamo esse botão no Xamarin.Forms? Se responder essa eu coloco como resolvido. Obrigado pela ajuda